# Глобальная переменная laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Как в laravel создать глобальную переменную которая будет отображаться во всех файлах шаблона?

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете использовать `view::share()`, примерно так:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use View;

//Создайте BaseController

class BaseController extends Controller {

 public $global_var2="Global Var 1";

 public function __construct() {
    $global_var2 = "Global Var 2";
    view::share($global_var1);
    view::share($global_var2);
    view::share("Global Var 3");
 }  

}

class YourController extends BaseController {

  public function __construct(){
     parent::__construct();
  }

  public function Index(){
    //Все переменные, объявленные в конструкторе BaseController, будут доступны
    return view('index'); 
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Переменные, доступные на любой странице, **находятся в папке config/**. Вызвать нужное значение можно через функцию **config()**.

```
# config/app.php
return [
'name' => 'Имя сайта',
];
```

## любая страница

```
config('app.name'); // Имя сайта
```